# Redux async middleware action doesn't have the necessary state on hand for api call

Tags: javascript, redux, middleware, react-redux

I have a react/redux app that works as following

1. User goes to host.com/id
2. Root app grabs the id and dispatches a `LOAD_USER_DETAILS_START` action w/ the id. This will return the user's id's for necessary for other 3rd party services.
3. Middleware catches that message and does an async call to our API w/ a callback to dispatch a `LOAD_USER_DETAILS_COMPLETE` message when the call is complete.
4. Middleware catches the `LOAD_USER_DETAILS_COMPLETE` and triggers several async calls to 3rd party API's with this new data.

My issue is that in step 4, I only have the `LOAD_USERS_DETAILS_COMPLETE` action and it's payload. There is other application state that I need (filters such as start and end time).

Currently I'm handling this by using `store.getState()`, as it is available through the middleware signature:

```
const asyncMiddlewareThing = store => next => action => {
    next(action);
    switch( action.type){
    case LOAD_USERS_DETAILS_COMPLETE:
        let { start, end } = store.getState().contactsFilter.timeframe;
        return store.dispatch(
            createFetchContactsStartMessage(action.payload.zuid, start, end)
        );
};
```

This makes me feel like I'm breaking the redux flow of information. Am I? I ask because I can see several situations where I will need to do this.

Comment: It is perfectly okay to access the state through `getState`. You might however find it cleaner to simply pass necessary information in your `action` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would use redux-thunk instead. It has option to get state in provided function.